# How to sort an array of big numbers stored as String?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

to sort the array we cannot use integer (or `Long`) parsing as size is very big.

for example

```
String[] arr = new String[] {
        "545434548549387551787458475822", 
        "555434548549387551787458475822",
        "7485204875485114857489579847438573954738574359287485284574"
    };
```

we have only integral part in string.

Comment: Have you tried [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html)?

Comment: You could sort by the String's length, resolving ties by alphabetical order.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem that would work as long as there are no leading zeroes in any of the strings. Otherwise, 01 could still come after 9.

Comment: @RifatRubayatulIslam biginteger is promising but I'm trying to operate on existing array only.

Comment: In that case, you can follow what @DawoodibnKareem suggested. But make sure there is no leading zero (see comment of @RobSpoor) and there is no negative number.

Comment: Create your own `Comperator<Strinng>` that parses the Strings from left to right (take in account if the lengths of both differ) until you can decide which value is greater.

Comment: What, in the context of Java, is `long long int`?

Comment: no leading zero, or just *exclude* leading zeros when calculating the length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Java's [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html) class along with a custom comparator to sort your array:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr = {
            "545434548549387551787458475822",
            "7485204875485114857489579847438573954738574359287485284574",
            "555434548549387551787458475822"
        };
        System.out.println("Before sorting:\n" + Arrays.toString(arr));
        Arrays.sort(arr, new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                return new BigInteger(o1).compareTo(new BigInteger(o2));
            }
        });
        // Alternative lambda custom comparator: 
        // Arrays.sort(arr, (o1, o2) -> new BigInteger(o1).compareTo(new BigInteger(o2)));
        System.out.println("After sorting:\n" + Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Before sorting:
[545434548549387551787458475822, 7485204875485114857489579847438573954738574359287485284574, 555434548549387551787458475822]
After sorting:
[545434548549387551787458475822, 555434548549387551787458475822, 7485204875485114857489579847438573954738574359287485284574]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot convert this into a standard `Number` instance (in Java), then use lexical sorting instead of numeric sorting.

### For the integral part of the number string:

1. **Ensure that all strings contain digits only.** Remove spaces, etc.
2. **Ensure that all strings are of the same length.** If they aren't, prefix the right number of zeros. Eg, if the length of the largest string is 10 and you have a string say `99`, then make it `0000000099`.
3. At this stage, the strings are ready to be compared. Simply, **sort the array as you would any string array.**

### For the decimal part of the number string:

If your array contains decimals, before sorting, you will have to extend the above algorithm to:

1. **Position the decimal point at a particular position in all strings**, say 11. You have to choose the position by analysing all the strings.
2. **The number of places after the decimal should also be same in all strings**. Again, in the end, the strings should all be the same length. But in the case of the decimal part, do this by padding the zeros at the end. (We need this padding only as a safety net to compare numerically equivalent number strings, like `"1.260"` and `"1.26"`. If we are sure that all numbers are different from each other, then we don't need this.)

Comment: Note that you don't have to actually modify the array. You can build a comparator on top of a padding function: `Array.sort(arr, Comparator.comparing(s -> pad(s)));`. It may be less efficient though.

Comment: @Sree lexical sorting does work here, point I was missing was of same length.

Comment: Instead of ensuring that all strings are of the same length or padding them (assuming that there are no leading zeros): sort them by length first and then lexicographically.
For decimal numbers you would have to sort on the position of the decimal marker.

Comment: @HansOlsson that works until a string has leading zeroes.

Comment: @RobSpoor - Yes, I added that as a caveat - and you would have to ensure that, or add some extra code to deal with leading zeros (and for decimal numbers also trailing zeros). But I still think that's a good tradeoff compared to modifying the strings.